# Convert radian to degree and add °

Tags: trigonometry, units, conversion

How can I convert a radian angle to a degree one and add ° after it?

I am using `N[(Pi/4)/Degree]`, but the output is `45.` with the point.

How can I have instead `45°`?

Comment: perhaps `Pi/4/. Pi -> 180 Degree`

Comment: I've edited the answer and reopened this question as I believe it will benefit future readers. That is subjective but there are precedents like this, I'm open to discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved that using

```
(Pi/4) * (180 Degree /Pi)
```

`Degree` is a symbol similar to `Pi`, it contains a value `Pi / 180` and it keeps the symbolic form unless used with finite precision numbers.

All functions in Mathematica work with radians so this symbol is a convenient form of a scaling factor: `40 Degree` is verbose but holds numerical value in radians.

**Extracting radians** is a simple as taking `N[40 Degree]`, or using `40.`.

Comment: The bad thing is it doesn't work when the given angle is numeric, e.g. when obtained using `NSolve[]`.